# How do I figure out why systemctl service "systemd-modules-load" fails?

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, kernel-module, usb-hid

For some time I've seen some red text flashing by during boot. Today I decided to look into it. The systemctl service `systemd-modules-load.service` is failing with this text:

```
tomas@bonus-debian:~$ sudo systemctl status systemd-modules-load
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since ma. 2015-11-09 02:58:48 CET; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 644 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 644 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

nov. 09 02:58:48 bonus-debian systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
nov. 09 02:58:48 bonus-debian systemd-modules-load[644]: Failed to find module '-r usbhid'
nov. 09 02:58:48 bonus-debian systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
nov. 09 02:58:48 bonus-debian systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
nov. 09 02:58:48 bonus-debian systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Unit entered failed state.
nov. 09 02:58:48 bonus-debian systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I thought I'd start out by Googling the issue:

[image: Screenshot]

Ouch.

My system doesn't seem to mind that the driver failed to load, as I haven't noticed a degraded experience, but I'd still like to fix it.

Since Google got me nowhere, I'm stuck already. I have no idea where to start looking.

**How do I figure out why systemctl service "systemd-modules-load" fails?**

Comment: Did you change a `udev` rule, by any chance?

Comment: Can you check in journalctl for the logs? Is it trying to load a module named "-r usbhid"?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I too had this issue. I was able to solve it by following the instructions on the Arch Linux [systemd wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Investigating_systemd_errors). Here is a summary of what I did :

1. Lets find the systemd services which fail to start

   ```
   $ systemctl --failed  
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   systemd-modules-load.service   loaded failed failed  Load Kernel Modules
   ```
2. Ok, we found a problem with systemd-modules-load service. We want to know more.

   ```
   $ systemctl status systemd-modules-load  
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules      
      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static)     
      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since So 2013-08-25 11:48:13 CEST; 32s ago  
        Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8).  
              man:modules-load.d(5)
     Process: 15630 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   ```

   If the Process ID is not listed, just restart the failed service with

   ```
   $ systemctl restart systemd-modules-load
   ```
3. Now we have the process id (PID) to investigate this error in depth. Enter the following command with the current Process ID (here: 15630):

   ```
   $ journalctl _PID=15630
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   -- Logs begin at Sa 2013-05-25 10:31:12 CEST, end at So 2013-08-25 11:51:17 CEST. --
   Aug 25 11:48:13 mypc systemd-modules-load[15630]: Failed to find module 'blacklist usblp'
   Aug 25 11:48:13 mypc systemd-modules-load[15630]: Failed to find module 'install usblp /bin/false'
   ```
4. We see that some of the kernel module configs have wrong settings. Therefore we have a look at these settings in /etc/modules-load.d/

   ```
   $ ls -Al /etc/modules-load.d/
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   ...  
   -rw-r--r--   1 root root    79  1. Dez 2012  blacklist.conf  
   -rw-r--r--   1 root root     1  2. Mär 14:30 encrypt.conf  
   -rw-r--r--   1 root root     3  5. Dez 2012  printing.conf  
   -rw-r--r--   1 root root     6 14. Jul 11:01 realtek.conf  
   -rw-r--r--   1 root root    65  2. Jun 23:01 virtualbox.conf  
   ...
   ```
5. The Failed to find module 'blacklist usblp' error message might be related to a wrong setting inside of blacklist.conf. Lets deactivate it with inserting a trailing # before each option we found via step 3:

   ```
   /etc/modules-load.d/blacklist.conf  
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   # blacklist usblp  
   # install usblp /bin/false
   ```
6. Now, try to start systemd-modules-load:

   ```
   $ systemctl restart systemd-modules-load
   ```

   If it was successful, this should not prompt anything. If you see any error, go back to step 3 and use the new PID for solving the errors left.

   If everything is ok, you can verify that the service was started successfully with:

   ```
   $ systemctl status systemd-modules-load
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static)
      Active: active (exited) since So 2013-08-25 12:22:31 CEST; 34s ago
        Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
              man:modules-load.d(5)
    Process: 19005 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Aug 25 12:22:31 mypc systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
   ```

Comment: Great answer – `_PID=` will now forever be in my toolbox. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, my `/etc/modules-load.d/` is empty, and it still says Failed to find module _blah_.  What now?

Comment: You may also want to check out `journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=systemd-modules-load.service`. Saves looking up the PID.

Comment: From user [bobafetthotmail](https://superuser.com/users/245396/bobafetthotmail): look also in `/usr/lib/modules-load.d/` for files loading modules, as there is where applications place the modules they need.  
The `/etc/modules-load.d/` is supposed to be for user configuration files.

Comment: I got `0 loaded units listed.`

Answer (score 1):

In my case a simple

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because of an incomplete droidcam uninstallation. I kept seeing the same error on boot (systemd-modules-load failed) even though all traces of the rogue module had been removed. The reference to the module was in the initial ramdisk. I had to create a new initial ramdisk by running "dracut" as root. To generate a new ramdisk, using bash syntax:

```
cd /boot
mv initramfs-$(uname -r).img initramfs-$(uname -r).img-bak
dracut initramfs-$(uname -r).img
```

Comment: Dracut command not found

Comment: @RahulGupta you can install `dracut` with your system's package manager, eg. `apt install dracut`.