# Ubuntu systemctl service fails with: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Tags: ubuntu, python, systemctl, mqtt

I am writing a python script that subscribes to some MQTT topics to localhost MQTT broker and when a message is pushed, the script will call a function in another script on the same directory to load the changes into an SQL database.

The script is working fine when run manually in terminal:

`python3 /directory/path/to/file/listen_mqtt.py`

However, I am trying to make this file execute automatically on Ubuntu system startup. I have created in a new service in:

`/lib/systemd/system/listen_mqtt_py.service`

The service description goes as follow:

```
[Unit]
Description=Listen Mqtt
After=mosquitto.service
Wants=network.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/bt/dev/dexter-mqtt-to-sql/listen_mqtt.py
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I also enabled the service and tried starting the service using:

`sudo systemctl enable listen_mqtt_py.service`

and

`sudo systemctl start listen_mqtt_py.service`

When rebooting the machine and also try running the service manually, I get the folling messages:

```
sudo systemctl status listen_mqtt_py.service
● listen_mqtt_py.service - Listen Mqtt
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/listen_mqtt_py.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-11-17 13:45:28 AEDT; 14s ago
    Process: 2206 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/bt/dev/dexter-mqtt-to-sql/listen_mqtt.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2206 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 17 13:45:27 btdms systemd[1]: Started Listen Mqtt.
Nov 17 13:45:28 btdms systemd[1]: listen_mqtt_py.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 17 13:45:28 btdms systemd[1]: listen_mqtt_py.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I did some research and found that this type of error could be related to calling the service too early before some required device has been loaded. Thus I tried altering the `After=` to `network-online.target` and also to `mosquitto.service`, however with no luck, service still exited with the same error messages.

Because the service does not fully execute even when I run `sudo systemctl start listen_mqtt_py.service` manually, so I suspect this is not due to another service not being loaded in time. It is some other reason. But I could not figure out why.

I am happy to also post the python script `listen_mqtt.py` if needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Turns out this is due to user privilege for python packages. Method to diagnosing this issue can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/997938/how-do-i-figure-out-why-systemctl-service-systemd-modules-load-fails).

Lets find the systemd services which fail to start

```
$ systemctl --failed
```

Found a problem with systemd-modules-load service. We want to know more.

```
$ systemctl status systemd-modules-load
```

Restart service if needed to regenerate the failling messge

```
$ systemctl restart systemd-modules-load
```

Now with the PID obtained:

```
journalctl _PID=15630
```

or

```
journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=systemd-modules-load.service
```

You should be able to see the error message generated on failure. Looking at the error messages, we know that the `paho` package has not been imported properly.

#### Solution

a. Install the related python package using root (which is what I did eventually)

To enter root CLI

```
sudo su -
```

b. Give root privilege to the python packages required in the service, I did not do this because I am not sure how it will behave with other users and I am not sure if root needs more privilege than a package only. Discussion about this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641414/python-import-of-local-module-failing-when-run-as-systemd-systemctl-service).

Comment: journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=systemd-modules-load.service

this command helps me to find the full log.

Answer (score 2):

journalctl -u charge_check.service -b
to chech what is going on wrong

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1143428)